# How to create a draggable component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I make a draggable component in React Native? I want that when the option is dragged from it's initial position and when I leave it, it should go back to the same position.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a library like, https://github.com/tongyy/react-native-draggable to achieve what you want

Or you can use pan responders. For detailed steps, you can take a look at this tutorial: https://moduscreate.com/blog/animated_drag_and_drop_with_react_native

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used `react-native-draggable-flatlist` and it worked for me. But how can I move the view just by using the drag icon and not the entire view?